# How to get the page id in custom plugin of wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new to the world of Php and word-press.
I want to edit the plugin with the page id.
I tried following options to get the page id but i couldn't get out nothing.

```
get_the_ID()
$post->ID
var_dump($wp_query)
```

all returns null.

The php file which i'm editing is inside a folder called inludes of plugin folder

But get_the_ID() is working fine in a php file which is in outside of this folder and that is the root folder of the plugin.

```
plugin folder
  include
     edit_page.php(Here i'm facing problem) 
 plugin.php
```

Your prompt response would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
global $post;
$page_ID = $post->ID;
var_dump($page_ID);
```

Comment: OK try:

$post = $wp_query->post;
$page_ID = $post->ID;
var_dump($page_ID);

Comment: This too returns null

Comment: Please can you edit your question to include all the code of your PHP file below the original question.